# Is $sgn(-\infty)\cdot -\infty = |\infty|$ and $sgn(\infty)\cdot \infty = |\infty|$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition

In Royden's *Real Analysis* there's a footnote stating:

[image]

where $E$ is a measurable set (this is a footnote in Holder's inequality).

My question is - why is it not the case that $sgn(f) \cdot f = |f|$ **everywhere**? Is it not the case that $sgn(-\infty)\cdot -\infty = |\infty|$ and $sgn(\infty)\cdot \infty = |\infty|$? I'm assuming this has to do with something not being well-defined but I can't say what it is.

Comment: Every real number $x$ satisfies $x\cdot sgn(x)=|x|$ , but $\infty$ is not a number , therefore the restriction.

Comment: @Peter so $sgn(x)$ is only defined for real numbers and therefore not defined for $\infty$? (just to make sure I see exactly where this fails)

Comment: Exactly, although often somewhat sloppy we calculate also with $\infty$ or $-\infty$ which helps for example to determine easily the limit for some polynomial for $x\to \infty$ or $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Which definitions could one provide in order to fix the argument?

Comment: May I ask what is the context of that footnote? What is $E$ here? Because I only know the phrase "almost everywhere" in the context of measure theory.

Comment: @hal4math of course, sorry - $E$ is a measurable set. Clarified that now in the question. Also added context (Holder's inequality).

Comment: @Anon. A Lebesgue measurable set of  the real line, I assume? In that case I think Rudin is just extra precise here. I guess you use this result in a context of a Lebesgue integral? In which case the equality only must hold Lebesgue almost everywhere and the function $f$ is only finite almost everywhere.

Comment: I noticed my last comment might be a bit beside your question. I am just so used to not care about "everywhere" in the context of measure theory. But in any case, I think @SassatelliGiulio answered your question, right?

Comment: To summarize, whether $\mathrm{sgn}$ is defined at $\infty$ is book dependent. From the footnote, it sounds like Royden does not define it there